# How to Handle SQLAlchemy Disconnects?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, dask, presto

I am using sqlalchemy to establish a connection to Presto and then using dask to parallelize reading the queries. The problem is the code isn't able to finish running due to a `TimeoutError`. What is the best way to implement retry logic when passing the SQLAlchemy Engine to Pandas?

Code Example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed

def parallelize_query(date):
    engine = create_engine(f'presto://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{catalog}/{schema}',
                                   connect_args={'protocol': 'https',
                                                 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': key}})

    q = query.format(date)
    data = pd.read_sql(q, conn)
    engine.dispose()
    return data

ddf = dd.from_delayed([delayed(parallelize_query)(d) for d in recent_dates])
```

Error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=<port>): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/statement/executing/20200427_231652_00087_rfnzc/yb90eab8fdeee4de5656afabc011dd8724e77bdcb/13761 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x913f95e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

Comment: does the problem persist when you do not destroy the engine with `.dispose`. How about setting `pool_timeout` as well? Also, what makes you so sure this is an sqlalchemy timeout and not a dask timeout

Comment: Because I've tried it w/o dask as well and still got a timeout